# Microsoft Bot Framework: Same name across sessions

Tags: node.js, session, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have the following code which attempts to set the user's name during a chat session. E.g. if the user writes the message **"Hi, my name is Bob"**, the bot will respond by greeting the user with his name, but only if the name was labeled as a "name" entity.

**The issue is that the name is globally set for every user that is currently chatting with the bot and not for the current user only. The bot will, in other words, call every user currently chatting Bob in this case.**

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })

    // Check if the message user sent matches LUIS intent "greetingsWithName"
    .matches('greetingsWithName', (session, args) => {
        // Attempt to set content of LUIS entity "name" to variable "name" 
        name = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'navn');

        // Check whether the name was successfully set or not
        if (!name) {
            session.send('Sorry, I didn't catch your name.')');
        } else {
        session.userData.userName = name.entity;
        session.send('Hi, ' + session.userData.userName);
    });
```

Later on I check in code whether the user has given his name to the bot or not during the session. If so, then say goodbye to the user with his name:

```
.matches('goodBye', (session) => {
    if (!session.userData.userName) {
        session.send('Good bye!');
    } else {
        session.send('Good bye, ' + session.userData.userName);
    }
})

bot.dialog('/', intents);
```

Here is the HTML code from the file that initiates the web chat session:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "The issue is that the name is globally set for every user that is currently chatting with the bot and not for the current user only": on which channel did you see this behavior? Emulator?

Comment: @NicolasR In a local HTML file that initiates the bot through the DirectLine channel using [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). I tried passing the HTML file around on other devices with different IPs/connected to different networks, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Ok, I suppose you always have the same User Id in your webchat in your html? That would explain the problem... Can you add the code of this html file please?

Comment: @NicolasR ah, that might be it actually. I used the [sample code from BotFramework-WebChat on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). Added the HTML code in the main post

Comment: @NicolasR The `user: { id: 'userid' }` field is currently set to `user: { id: 'You'}`

Comment: I added an answer. You can also add a `name` property for the display if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the name of the user in `userData`, which is logical.

But in your tester, you set the same user id for every webchat user:

```
user: { id: 'userid' }
```

So every user will point to the same `userData` as the key is a combination of the channel name and the user id (`activity.ChannelId`, `activity.From.Id` in C#).

You can avoid this by generating unique identifiers for every webchat user, for example using https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-random

In that case, `user: { id: uuid() }`.

Moreover if you need to set a display name, add `name: '...'` to the definition of user: `user: { id: uuid(), name: 'You' }`.

Comment: By creating a function that generated a random user ID and pass that into the `user: { id: createUserId() }`, the bot was able to distinguish between sessions. Thank you!

Comment: There are many solutions to change the Id yes, the main fact was that the same user.id was used accross calls. Glad it helped